# SQL IF ELSE for Inner join with linked dependency

Tags: sql

I am trying to join data based on two selection criteria with an if else case.
I have a table with exchange rates (dbo.DATA_EXCHANGE_RATE), one with years (dbo.DATA_EXCHANGE_RATE.YEAR_OBJ_REF) and one with currencies (dbo.DATA_EXCHANGE_RATE.CURRECY_OBJ_REF). If the currency is Euro I want to select my exchange rate only based on currency otherwise based on year and currency. What I have is

```
select dbo.DATA_EXCHANGE_RATE.EXCHANGE_RATE_CAPTION
from dbo.DATA_EXCHANGE_RATE
inner join dbo.measures
on(CASE WHEN dbo.measures.CURRECY_OBJ_REF =
         (select DATA_ID from dbo.DATA_CURRENCY where CURRENCY_CAPTION = 'T-EUR')
   THEN
      dbo.DATA_EXCHANGE_RATE.CURRECY_OBJ_REF = dbo.measures.CURRECY_OBJ_REF
   ELSE
      dbo.DATA_EXCHANGE_RATE.YEAR_OBJ_REF = dbo.measures.YEAR_OBJ_REF
      and dbo.DATA_EXCHANGE_RATE.CURRECY_OBJ_REF = dbo.measures.CURRECY_OBJ_REF
   END)
```

but this throws an error:

```
  Failed!
Incorrect syntax near '='
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Your `CASE` expression is broken, and I'm not sure I understand your join logic.  Can you show us some sample data and expected output here?

Comment: It's generally better to use `AND`/`OR` in ON and WHERE clauses, instead of `case` expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CASE` doesn't work like `if` in procedural languages, it returns an atomic value. It can not be used for program flow in this manner. What you want is `AND` and `OR`:

```
select      DER.EXCHANGE_RATE_CAPTION
FROM        dbo.DATA_EXCHANGE_RATE DER
inner join  dbo.measures M
        ON  (
                    M.CURRECY_OBJ_REF = (SELECT DATA_ID from dbo.DATA_CURRENCY where CURRENCY_CAPTION = 'T-EUR')
                AND DER.CURRECY_OBJ_REF = M.CURRECY_OBJ_REF
            )
        OR  (
                    M.CURRECY_OBJ_REF <> (SELECT DATA_ID from dbo.DATA_CURRENCY where CURRENCY_CAPTION = 'T-EUR')
                AND DER.YEAR_OBJ_REF = M.YEAR_OBJ_REF
                AND DER.CURRECY_OBJ_REF = M.CURRECY_OBJ_REF
            )
```

I've also used aliases to improve readability.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following query maintains your intended logic, minus the syntax errors:

```
SELECT dbo.DATA_EXCHANGE_RATE.EXCHANGE_RATE_CAPTION
FROM dbo.DATA_EXCHANGE_RATE t1
INNER JOIN dbo.measures t2
ON
(
    dbo.measures.CURRECY_OBJ_REF = (select DATA_ID from dbo.DATA_CURRENCY
                                    where CURRENCY_CAPTION = 'T-EUR')      AND
    t1.CURRECY_OBJ_REF = t2.CURRECY_OBJ_REF
)
OR
(
    dbo.measures.CURRECY_OBJ_REF <> (select DATA_ID from dbo.DATA_CURRENCY
                                     where CURRENCY_CAPTION = 'T-EUR')     AND
    t1.YEAR_OBJ_REF = t2.YEAR_OBJ_REF        AND
    t1.CURRECY_OBJ_REF = t2.CURRECY_OBJ_REF
)
```

I don't like the idea of putting a subquery into the `ON` clause, because it feels weird.  I suspect if we were to see your data, we might be able to improve upon this query.

Comment: @ Tim Biegeleisen: This throws the following exception: Failed!
The multi-part identifier "dbo.measures.CURRECY_OBJ_REF" could not be bound
0/1 Completed! but the code from @HoneyBadger works fine for me

Comment: @horseshoe I corrected the name of your table that's all.

Answer (score 0):

```html
Declare @Query as nvarchar(max) = 'select dbo.DATA_EXCHANGE_RATE.EXCHANGE_RATE_CAPTION
from dbo.DATA_EXCHANGE_RATE
                     inner join dbo.measures
on (CASE WHEN dbo.measures.CURRECY_OBJ_REF =(select DATA_ID from dbo.DATA_CURRENCY where CURRENCY_CAPTION = ''T-EUR'')
   THEN
      dbo.DATA_EXCHANGE_RATE.CURRECY_OBJ_REF = dbo.measures.CURRECY_OBJ_REF
   ELSE
      dbo.DATA_EXCHANGE_RATE.YEAR_OBJ_REF = dbo.measures.YEAR_OBJ_REF
      and dbo.DATA_EXCHANGE_RATE.CURRECY_OBJ_REF = dbo.measures.CURRECY_OBJ_REF
   END)'

   EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @Query
```

Comment: @HoneyBadger Not expect out put just try put my logic because we have not table structure.

Comment: But you can't use `CASE` this way. You just put the original query in a dynamic query, what is the difference?

Comment: @Singh Kailash: This throws the same error I had before: Failed!
Incorrect syntax near '='
0/1 Completed!

Comment: can you send sample table

Answer (score 0):

Replace it with an OR expression

```
declare @EURO int;
select @EURO = DATA_ID from dbo.DATA_CURRENCY where CURRENCY_CAPTION = 'T-EUR';

select dbo.DATA_EXCHANGE_RATE.EXCHANGE_RATE_CAPTION
from dbo.DATA_EXCHANGE_RATE
      inner join dbo.measures on (dbo.measures.CURRECY_OBJ_REF = @EURO and dbo.DATA_EXCHANGE_RATE.CURRECY_OBJ_REF = dbo.measures.CURRECY_OBJ_REF) or
                                 (dbo.measures.CURRECY_OBJ_REF <> @EURO and dbo.DATA_EXCHANGE_RATE.YEAR_OBJ_REF = dbo.measures.YEAR_OBJ_REF and dbo.DATA_EXCHANGE_RATE.CURRECY_OBJ_REF = dbo.measures.CURRECY_OBJ_REF);
```